# How to create a responsive app screen with transparent background in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to create a app screen that have a transparent background.

Like this,

### Here is the result i need

[image]

I tried to create one using a 9 patch image but it's lost padding and margin, when changing the device size. Then i create images for mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxdpi and xxxhdpi screens, but still same issue. It lost padding and margins and not align correctly. So how to create a app screen like this in android without using images. Sometimes this is a stupid question, but i spent two weeks and i cannot find a better way. I hope you can help me. Thank you,

Comment: set `Activity`'s theme to dialog.

Comment: Maybe what u are looking 4 is a desktop widget?

Comment: @zozelfelfo. Thank you. May be. I try it too

Comment: I think changing app theme to `dialog` is the solution. Thank you guys